# Speaking less-than-unit decimals

Tags: numbers, listening

As far as I know, decimals smaller than unit can be read, for instance:

"0.38" -> "Point 3, 8"

But, in [one of the IELTS sample listening tasks](https://www.ielts.org/about-the-test//-/media/files/listening-sample-task-type-1.ashx) (around 1:30), they say something like

"0.75" -> "**north?** 7 5"

"0.5" -> "**north?** 5"

What does he really say?, cause I am pretty sure he does not say "Oh" for the zero.

Feel free to move this question to ell, since I am not sure where to ask this.

Comment: "Point oh three eight" would be interpreted to mean ".038".

Comment: And "naught point seven five" is "0.75".  ("Naught" is not commonly spoken in the US -- it would be either "oh" or "zero".)

Comment: @HotLicks Oops, my bad. Edited now

Comment: Why do you still say "north"?

Comment: It is definitely "naught point seven five" and "naught point five", which I am led to believe is relatively normal in British usage.

Comment: @Hellion I think we Brits say _oh_ not _naught_. And just to be even more difficult I think we spell it _nought_ anyway.

Comment: @NigelJ - It's certainly possible that Brits say *oh* more often than they say *nought*, but they do say it (I hear it regularly on BBC and when British correspondents speak on NPR); whereas Americans pretty much **never** say *nought*. I believe you are right about the spelling, when it comes specifically to the digit zero. (*Naught* would mean "nothing", and is commonly used in the phrase "all for naught", both in British and American English.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because transcription questions are too localized for the ELU charter.

Comment: I think it's not so much asking for transcription as it's asking "what the heck is this word I've never heard before?" And because they have no idea what the word is, they don't quite know how to spell it and aren't even sure if they heard it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is saying *nought*:

[from [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nought):]

> NOUN *British* The digit 0.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?